# Oracle change notification Exception

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

My one of the table holds data for business transactions and I have to run a job when there's no transaction for interval 5 minutes, I am trying to achieve this using Timer() in java. So to get notified if any transaction is executed I need some triggering ( I do not have code access as it is 3rd party tool ) for that purpose I am using database change notification.

However while running this I get below error very often. I am using *java 1.6*,  *ojdbc6.jar* for connection purpose and the application is running on weblogic with oracle 11g database.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540) at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:139) at oracle.jdbc.driver.NTFConnection.unmarshalOneNSPacket(NTFCon‌​nection.java:334) at oracle.jdbc.driver.NTFConnection.run(NTFConnection.java:182)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please modify the example http://appcrawler.com/wordpress/2012/08/28/jdbc-and-oracle-database-change-notification/ for your listener and check if issue still exists. My understading that issue is not related to Oracle DB, but part of Java realization of your code. Please, add java tag into your question as well.